# Bullet Shooting in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

Hi i have below cod for my android project and when i look Up and Down and shoot a bullet the bullet shooting direction be wrong where is the problem?

here is a vidoe of my project.

http://www.mediafire.com/file/9xhxvyxds4cyego/2016-11-27_15-07-39.mp4

FirstPerson

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityStandardAssets.CrossPlatformInput;
using UnityStandardAssets.Utility;
using Random = UnityEngine.Random;

namespace UnityStandardAssets.Characters.FirstPerson
{
    [RequireComponent(typeof (CharacterController))]
    [RequireComponent(typeof (AudioSource))]
    public class FirstPersonController : MonoBehaviour
    {
        [SerializeField] private bool m_IsWalking;
        [SerializeField] private float m_WalkSpeed;
        [SerializeField] private float m_LookSpeed=4;

        [SerializeField] private float m_RunSpeed;
        [SerializeField] [Range(0f, 1f)] private float m_RunstepLenghten;
        [SerializeField] private float m_JumpSpeed;
        [SerializeField] private float m_StickToGroundForce;
        [SerializeField] private float m_GravityMultiplier;
        [SerializeField] private MouseLook m_MouseLook;
        [SerializeField] private bool m_UseFovKick;
        [SerializeField] private FOVKick m_FovKick = new FOVKick();
        [SerializeField] private bool m_UseHeadBob;
        [SerializeField] private CurveControlledBob m_HeadBob = new CurveControlledBob();
        [SerializeField] private LerpControlledBob m_JumpBob = new LerpControlledBob();
        [SerializeField] private float m_StepInterval;
        [SerializeField] private AudioClip[] m_FootstepSounds;    // an array of footstep sounds that will be randomly selected from.
        [SerializeField] private AudioClip m_JumpSound;           // the sound played when character leaves the ground.
        [SerializeField] private AudioClip m_LandSound;           // the sound played when character touches back on ground.

        private Camera m_Camera;
        private bool m_Jump;
        private float m_YRotation;
        private Vector2 m_Input;
        private Vector3 m_MoveDir = Vector3.zero;
        private CharacterController m_CharacterController;
        private CollisionFlags m_CollisionFlags;
        private bool m_PreviouslyGrounded;
        private Vector3 m_OriginalCameraPosition;
        private float m_StepCycle;
        private float m_NextStep;
        private bool m_Jumping;
        private AudioSource m_AudioSource;
        public GameObject AK;
        // Use this for initialization
        private void Start()
        {
            Instantiate(AK);

            m_CharacterController = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
            m_Camera = Camera.main;
            m_OriginalCameraPosition = m_Camera.transform.localPosition;
            m_FovKick.Setup(m_Camera);
            m_HeadBob.Setup(m_Camera, m_StepInterval);
            m_StepCycle = 0f;
            m_NextStep = m_StepCycle/2f;
            m_Jumping = false;
            m_AudioSource = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
            m_MouseLook.Init(transform , m_Camera.transform);
        }


        // Update is called once per frame
        private void Update()
        {
            RotateView();
            // the jump state needs to read here to make sure it is not missed
            if (!m_Jump)
            {
                m_Jump = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetButtonDown("Jump");
            }

            if (!m_PreviouslyGrounded && m_CharacterController.isGrounded)
            {
                StartCoroutine(m_JumpBob.DoBobCycle());
                PlayLandingSound();
                m_MoveDir.y = 0f;
                m_Jumping = false;
            }
            if (!m_CharacterController.isGrounded && !m_Jumping && m_PreviouslyGrounded)
            {
                m_MoveDir.y = 0f;
            }

            m_PreviouslyGrounded = m_CharacterController.isGrounded;
        }


        private void PlayLandingSound()
        {
            m_AudioSource.clip = m_LandSound;
            m_AudioSource.Play();
            m_NextStep = m_StepCycle + .5f;
        }


        private void FixedUpdate()
        {
            float speed;
            GetInput(out speed);
            // always move along the camera forward as it is the direction that it being aimed at
            Vector3 desiredMove = transform.forward*m_Input.y + transform.right*m_Input.x;

            // get a normal for the surface that is being touched to move along it
            RaycastHit hitInfo;
            Physics.SphereCast(transform.position, m_CharacterController.radius, Vector3.down, out hitInfo,
                               m_CharacterController.height/2f);
            desiredMove = Vector3.ProjectOnPlane(desiredMove, hitInfo.normal).normalized;

            m_MoveDir.x = desiredMove.x*speed;
            m_MoveDir.z = desiredMove.z*speed;


            if (m_CharacterController.isGrounded)
            {
                m_MoveDir.y = -m_StickToGroundForce;

                if (m_Jump)
                {
                    m_MoveDir.y = m_JumpSpeed;
                    PlayJumpSound();
                    m_Jump = false;
                    m_Jumping = true;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                m_MoveDir += Physics.gravity*m_GravityMultiplier*Time.fixedDeltaTime;
            }
            m_CollisionFlags = m_CharacterController.Move(m_MoveDir*Time.fixedDeltaTime);

            ProgressStepCycle(speed);
            UpdateCameraPosition(speed);
        }


        private void PlayJumpSound()
        {
            m_AudioSource.clip = m_JumpSound;
            m_AudioSource.Play();
        }


        private void ProgressStepCycle(float speed)
        {
            if (m_CharacterController.velocity.sqrMagnitude > 0 && (m_Input.x != 0 || m_Input.y != 0))
            {
                m_StepCycle += (m_CharacterController.velocity.magnitude + (speed*(m_IsWalking ? 1f : m_RunstepLenghten)))*
                             Time.fixedDeltaTime;
            }

            if (!(m_StepCycle > m_NextStep))
            {
                return;
            }

            m_NextStep = m_StepCycle + m_StepInterval;

            PlayFootStepAudio();
        }


        private void PlayFootStepAudio()
        {
            if (!m_CharacterController.isGrounded)
            {
                return;
            }
            // pick & play a random footstep sound from the array,
            // excluding sound at index 0
            int n = Random.Range(1, m_FootstepSounds.Length);
            m_AudioSource.clip = m_FootstepSounds[n];
            m_AudioSource.PlayOneShot(m_AudioSource.clip);
            // move picked sound to index 0 so it's not picked next time
            m_FootstepSounds[n] = m_FootstepSounds[0];
            m_FootstepSounds[0] = m_AudioSource.clip;
        }


        private void UpdateCameraPosition(float speed)
        {
            Vector3 newCameraPosition;
            if (!m_UseHeadBob)
            {
                return;
            }
            if (m_CharacterController.velocity.magnitude > 0 && m_CharacterController.isGrounded)
            {
                m_Camera.transform.localPosition =
                    m_HeadBob.DoHeadBob(m_CharacterController.velocity.magnitude +
                                      (speed*(m_IsWalking ? 1f : m_RunstepLenghten)));
                newCameraPosition = m_Camera.transform.localPosition;
                newCameraPosition.y = m_Camera.transform.localPosition.y - m_JumpBob.Offset();
            }
            else
            {
                newCameraPosition = m_Camera.transform.localPosition;
                newCameraPosition.y = m_OriginalCameraPosition.y - m_JumpBob.Offset();
            }
            m_Camera.transform.localPosition = newCameraPosition;
        }


        private void GetInput(out float speed)
        {
            // Read input
            float horizontal = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
            float vertical = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");

            bool waswalking = m_IsWalking;

#if !MOBILE_INPUT
            // On standalone builds, walk/run speed is modified by a key press.
            // keep track of whether or not the character is walking or running
            m_IsWalking = !Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift);
#endif
            // set the desired speed to be walking or running
            speed = m_IsWalking ? m_WalkSpeed : m_RunSpeed;
            m_Input = new Vector2(horizontal, vertical);

            // normalize input if it exceeds 1 in combined length:
            if (m_Input.sqrMagnitude > 1)
            {
                m_Input.Normalize();
            }

            // handle speed change to give an fov kick
            // only if the player is going to a run, is running and the fovkick is to be used
            if (m_IsWalking != waswalking && m_UseFovKick && m_CharacterController.velocity.sqrMagnitude > 0)
            {
                StopAllCoroutines();
                StartCoroutine(!m_IsWalking ? m_FovKick.FOVKickUp() : m_FovKick.FOVKickDown());
            }
        }


        private void RotateView()
        {
            #if !MOBILE_INPUT

            m_MouseLook.LookRotation (transform, m_Camera.transform);
            m_Camera.transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3 (-m_MouseLook.y, m_Camera.transform.localEulerAngles.y,
                                                                m_Camera.transform.localEulerAngles.z);
            transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3 (0, m_MouseLook.x, 0);

#else
            Vector2  m_MouseLook= new Vector2( CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxisRaw("HorizontalLook")
                                              ,CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxisRaw("VerticalLook"));
            float Camx=m_Camera.transform.localEulerAngles.x;

            if((Camx>280 && Camx<=360) || 
               (Camx >=0 && Camx<80) ||
               (Camx>=80 && Camx<180 && m_MouseLook.y>0) ||
               (Camx>180 && Camx<=280 && m_MouseLook.y<0))
            {
                m_Camera.transform.localEulerAngles += new Vector3 (-m_MouseLook.y*m_LookSpeed, m_Camera.transform.localEulerAngles.y,
                                                                    m_Camera.transform.localEulerAngles.z);
            //  AK.transform.localEulerAngles=m_Camera.transform.localEulerAngles;
            }


            transform.localEulerAngles += new Vector3 (0, m_MouseLook.x*m_LookSpeed, 0);

#endif

        m_YRotation = m_MouseLook.y;

        }


        private void OnControllerColliderHit(ControllerColliderHit hit)
        {
            Rigidbody body = hit.collider.attachedRigidbody;
            //dont move the rigidbody if the character is on top of it
            if (m_CollisionFlags == CollisionFlags.Below)
            {
                return;
            }

            if (body == null || body.isKinematic)
            {
                return;
            }
            body.AddForceAtPosition(m_CharacterController.velocity*0.1f, hit.point, ForceMode.Impulse);
        }
    }
}
```

Joystick cod-------------///////////////

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

namespace UnityStandardAssets.CrossPlatformInput
{
    public class Joystick : MonoBehaviour, IPointerDownHandler, IPointerUpHandler, IDragHandler
    {
        public enum AxisOption
        {
            // Options for which axes to use
            Both, // Use both
            OnlyHorizontal, // Only horizontal
            OnlyVertical // Only vertical
        }

        public int MovementRange = 100;
        public AxisOption axesToUse = AxisOption.Both; // The options for the axes that the still will use
        public string horizontalAxisName = "Horizontal"; // The name given to the horizontal axis for the cross platform input
        public string verticalAxisName = "Vertical"; // The name given to the vertical axis for the cross platform input

        Vector3 m_StartPos;
        bool m_UseX; // Toggle for using the x axis
        bool m_UseY; // Toggle for using the Y axis
        CrossPlatformInputManager.VirtualAxis m_HorizontalVirtualAxis; // Reference to the joystick in the cross platform input
        CrossPlatformInputManager.VirtualAxis m_VerticalVirtualAxis; // Reference to the joystick in the cross platform input

        void OnEnable()
        {
            CreateVirtualAxes();
        }

        void Start()
        {
            m_StartPos = transform.position;
        }

        void UpdateVirtualAxes(Vector3 value)
        {
            var delta = m_StartPos - value;
            delta.y = -delta.y;
            delta /= MovementRange;
            if (m_UseX)
            {
                m_HorizontalVirtualAxis.Update(-delta.x);
            }

            if (m_UseY)
            {
                m_VerticalVirtualAxis.Update(delta.y);
            }
        }

        void CreateVirtualAxes()
        {
            // set axes to use
            m_UseX = (axesToUse == AxisOption.Both || axesToUse == AxisOption.OnlyHorizontal);
            m_UseY = (axesToUse == AxisOption.Both || axesToUse == AxisOption.OnlyVertical);

            // create new axes based on axes to use
            if (m_UseX)
            {
                m_HorizontalVirtualAxis = new CrossPlatformInputManager.VirtualAxis(horizontalAxisName);
                CrossPlatformInputManager.RegisterVirtualAxis(m_HorizontalVirtualAxis);
            }
            if (m_UseY)
            {
                m_VerticalVirtualAxis = new CrossPlatformInputManager.VirtualAxis(verticalAxisName);
                CrossPlatformInputManager.RegisterVirtualAxis(m_VerticalVirtualAxis);
            }
        }


        public void OnDrag(PointerEventData data)
        {
            Vector3 newPos = Vector3.zero;

            if (m_UseX)
            {
                int delta = (int)(data.position.x - m_StartPos.x);
                delta = Mathf.Clamp(delta, - MovementRange, MovementRange);
                newPos.x = delta;
            }

            if (m_UseY)
            {
                int delta = (int)(data.position.y - m_StartPos.y);
                delta = Mathf.Clamp(delta, -MovementRange, MovementRange);
                newPos.y = delta;
            }
            transform.position = new Vector3(m_StartPos.x + newPos.x, m_StartPos.y + newPos.y, m_StartPos.z + newPos.z);
            UpdateVirtualAxes(transform.position);
        }


        public void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData data)
        {
            transform.position = m_StartPos;
            UpdateVirtualAxes(m_StartPos);
        }


        public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData data) { }

        void OnDisable()
        {
            // remove the joysticks from the cross platform input
            if (m_UseX)
            {
                m_HorizontalVirtualAxis.Remove();
            }
            if (m_UseY)
            {
                m_VerticalVirtualAxis.Remove();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Shooting Bullet

```
#pragma strict
//---------------------------------------------------------
//---------------------------------------------------------
var Mig29_Fulcrum:GameObject;
var AK:Rigidbody;
var muzzel:GameObject;
var bullet:Rigidbody;
var Speed:int=700;
private var Fire:int=0;
private var Shooting:boolean =false;
private var gun:GameObject;

private   var fireDelay:float  = 0f; // the delay between shots

function Start () {

gun=GameObject.FindWithTag("MyGun");

//var AkGun:Rigidbody=Instantiate(AK,this.transform.position,this.transform.rotation);
//var b:Rigidbody=Instantiate(bullet,this.transform.position,this.transform.rotation);

}

function Update () {


if(Input.GetButtonDown("Fire2"))
{
//gun.GetComponent.<Animation>().Play("Jump");

Shooting=true;
}

if(Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
{
Shooting=false;

}
if(Shooting)
{
    AutoFire(0.08f);
}

}

  function FireWeapon()
    {
        Debug.Log("Fire!!!");

  GetComponent.<AudioSource>().Play();
  gun.GetComponent.<Animation>().Play("GunFire");

var m:GameObject=Instantiate(muzzel,this.transform.position,this.transform.rotation);
m.transform.Rotate(Vector3(-90,0,0));
m.transform.Rotate(Vector3(0,Random.Range(0,180),0));
Destroy(m,0.015);

var b:Rigidbody=Instantiate(bullet,this.transform.position,this.transform.rotation);
b.AddForce(this.transform.forward*Speed);


    }

    // The function below activates the FireWeapon function
    function AutoFire( fireRate:float)
    {
        if (fireDelay < fireRate)
        {
            fireDelay += Time.deltaTime;
        }

        if (fireDelay >= fireRate)
        {
            FireWeapon();
            fireDelay = 0f;
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the video, the problem is that your bullets are fired based on the position and orientation of the *camera*, not the *gun*. This is normally preferable in most first person shooter games (eg. Counter-Strike and similar), but maybe not in your case (since you're using mobile joystick controls).

This behavior is caused by the following code:

```
var b:Rigidbody=Instantiate(bullet,this.transform.position,this.transform.rotation);
b.AddForce(this.transform.forward*Speed);
```

Since you're using the position and rotation of `this.transform`, the script refers to the transform of the camera you attached the script to.

If you wish your game to behave differently, you should consider referring to the transform component of the gun instead (conveniently, in your cased stored in the variable `gun`):

```
var b:Rigidbody=Instantiate(bullet,gun.transform.position,gun.transform.rotation);
b.AddForce(gun.transform.forward*Speed);
```

Note that this might not work if your gun's anchor isn't at the muzzle and its `forward` vector doesn't point in the direction you want the bullet to come out. In that case, you might want to add to the gun an empty child GameObject that's properly positioned and oriented.